# How to randomly extract column from the data of an excel file with specifically setting a condition in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to randomly extract some data from my excel file through colab (Python).

And I need to extract those datas that are labeled with a specific condition.

For example, some data at a specific column are not labeled, while some are labeled with 'true' and 'false'.

If I want to extract those that are only labeled with 'true', what is the specific code that can help me to do with it?

```
finance_data = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/MyDrive/~.xlsx)
len(finance_data)
finance_data.sample(n=10) ~~~
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I believe you are looking for subsetting data tutorial. You can learn about it from this official documentation : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I was looking for :)